# How to check visibility/actionability in Cypress using Clarity Design

Tags: angular, cypress, vmware-clarity

## Versions

- [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) 3.6.1
- [Angular](https://angular.io/) 8.2.13
- [Clarity](https://clarity.design/) 2.3.1

## Problem

For Cypress actions like `cy.click()` or `cy.check()`, Cypress first checks if the element is actionable according to a [list of pre-defined criteria](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Actionability).

Clarity components like `clrToggle` wrap an input with `type="checkbox"`. When trying to interact with the element via `cy.check()`, the test would fail since the addressed input is not visible due to being wrapped by the Clarity component.

My current workaround is to use `cy.check({force: true})`, which works fine but completely bypasses the actionability check, which would definitely be nice to have in many situations.

## Screenshot

- Test log **without workaround** (full error below):
  [image]

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

<input _ngcontent-woh-c23="" clrtoggle="" data-cy="active-toggle" formcontrolname="isActive" id="isActive" name="isActive" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="isActive" aria-describedby="isActive-helper" ng-reflect-id="isActive" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">

This element '<input#isActive.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid>' is not visible because it has CSS property: 'position: fixed' and its being covered by another element:

<label _ngcontent-woh-c23="" for="isActive" class="clr-control-label" ng-reflect-for-attr="isActive">Aktiv</label>

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

https://on.cypress.io/element-cannot-be-interacted-with
```

- Test log **with `{force: true}` workaround**:
  [image]

## Question

As I know that Clarity also uses Cypress for internal testing I'd like to know: **Is there a way to properly use Cypress testing for Clarity components?**

Comment: Internally we use Cypress+Applitools for visual regression testing. We are slowly migrating away from Gemini for this. 

The current ToggleSpec() is very simple. Cypress visits the /toggle page and we use Applitools plugin to take the screen shot for comparison.

Comment: `clrToggle` is a directive applied in the application side, it doesn't wrap the input. It should be visible and it should be clickable with cypress.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get that you never had any issues with components such as the toggle being hidden for Cypress?

Comment: Yes. If the toggle is in the test component it should be clickable.